# Proving the non-differentiability of $|x| + x$.

Tags: limits, derivatives, absolute-value

For the function $f(x) = |x| + x$, how can one prove that it is not differentiable at the point $x = 0$? Specifically, I wish to use the Definition of the Derivative

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

to attain two non-equal limiting values by taking $\Delta x$ to be first positive, and then negative.

It was my original thought to rewrite $f(x)$ as

$$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
 2x&\text{if}\, x\geq 0\\
 0&\text{if}\, x < 0
\end{cases}
$$

and then take the derivative for each separate case and show that they aren't equal, but I wish to use the above definition with both a positive and a negative $\Delta x$, and so the cases method would fall out of line with that.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not differentiable at $0$ because it's a sum of differentiable ($x$) and not differentiable ($|x|$) function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\Delta x>0$, then $$\frac{f(\Delta x)-f(0)}{\Delta x}=2,$$whereas if $\Delta x<0$, then $$\frac{f(\Delta x)-f(0)}{\Delta x}=0.$$Therefore$$\lim_{\Delta x\to0^+}\frac{f(\Delta x)-f(0)}{\Delta x}=2\neq0=\lim_{\Delta x\to0^-}\frac{f(\Delta x)-f(0)}{\Delta x}.$$

Comment: How do you which case to use for $\Delta x$ greater than or less than 0? In the definition, $2x$ is used if $x \geq 0$, were $x = x + \Delta x$. So, knowing not the value of $x$ and only that $\Delta x$ is near 0, how do we know if $x + \Delta x$ is positive or negative to decide which case to use?

Comment: @JamieCorkhill My mistake. I wrote $x$, but I had $0$ in my mind. I suppose that it is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: show $f'(0^{+}) \neq f'(0^{-})$